# MS Access split database query issues

Tags: ms-access, database-design

I have a split MS Access database that 3 different users are utilizing, each with their own copy of the front end in different locations from the backend.  There is also a copy of the front end in the same drive/folder as the backend.  When I run reports from the front end located in the same back end folder, they are fine.  When run from another drive/folder location, the reports run, but don't have a complete set of data.  Any advice on what might be causing this?  Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like some tables are linked to different or no backend.

Comment: Thanks Gustav.  The query is based on two tables and I checked the linking to make sure it's correct.  If I open either of the tables in the front end (the one not saved in the same area as the backend), I can see that all of the data is there, it just won't show on the report even though it does on the front end that is saved near the back end.  Not sure if that helps.  Let me know if there is any other information I can provide.

Comment: Try to interchange the frontends.

Answer (score 0):

You can get access errors by having multiple users trying to change the same recordset.

Could you implement a SQL backend, and link all the individual ACCESS DBs to the SQL server? This would limit the possibility of multiple versions of the same data.